# Object notation in custom JavaScript code in jTemplates

Tags: javascript, jtemplates

I'm using `jTemplates jQuery` plugin and I have a JavaScript function that accepts an object as an argument. I'm calling this function from my template and trying to pass a parameter in the following form of short object notation:

```
{jQuery.imgCheckBox.render({id: 'check', checked: true, disabled: false})}
```

But it seems that `jTemplates` doesn't allow me to use curly braces within this block of custom code.

I've studied `jTemplates` documenatation but haven't found any info on this issue.
Is there any way to use short object notation in custom JavasScript code within `jTemplates`?